# How to save and load Markdown with React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, markdown, blockstack

I'm new to React. I have an assignment building a **Markdown Editor** with **Blockstack ID** integrated.

**I'm trying to save the content into a JSON file then load it again in the editor, but it seems like it can't load that JSON file back to the editor.**

*Here's some code:*

```
import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';

    <MDEditor
       onChange={e=>this.updateMarkdown(e)}
       value={this.state.markdown}
    />


             <button
              onClick={e => this.saveNewText(e)}>
              Submit Changes
             </button>
```

```
  updateMarkdown(editor, data, value) {
    this.setState({ markdown: value})
  }


  saveNewText() {
    const { userSession } = this.props
    let currentDocument = this.state.currentDocument
    let newDocument = {
      md: this.state.markdown,
      created_at: Date.now()
    }

    const options = { encrypt: true }
    userSession.putFile('Document.json', JSON.stringify(newDocument), options)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          currentDocument:newDocument
        })
      })
   }

  loadNewText() {
      const { userSession } = this.props
      const options = { decrypt: true }
      userSession.getFile('Document.json', options)
      .then((file) => {
          var docFile = JSON.parse(file || '[]');
          this.setState({
            currentDocument:docFile,
            markdown:docFile.md
          });
      })
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { userSession } = this.props
    this.setState({
      person: new Person(userSession.loadUserData().profile),
      username: userSession.loadUserData().username
    });
    this.loadNewText();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [react-blockstack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-blockstack#persistent-data-storage) package provides a `useFile` hook for React to persist content in the Blockstack Gaia storage:

```js
const [document, setDocument] = useFile('Document.json')
```

This replaces most of your code except transformation between text and JSON.